# Update a Mapfield with spread operator in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, babeljs

Excerpt from the reducer:

```
case PRODUCT_SAVED_OK:
  return {
    ...state,
    isFetching: false,
    didInvalidate: false
    // TODO how is this done?
    //items[action.item.id]: action.item
    // TODO Push the new ID if it was a new Product
  };
```

So when a product is saved I send a post. If the post comes back it sends the new entity with it (action.item)

The state looks like this:

```
state = {
  isFetching: false,
  didInvalidate: true,
  items: new Map(),
  itemsIds: []
}
```

So items is actually map(id -> product) and I also got an id array. How do I update these now? I think I saw something which worked but I cannot find it anymore. ...items and ...state.items didn't work though.

On a sidenode: Is this the way its supposed to be done? Not reproducing data and just have id's in reducers which manage selected stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A map is represented as `[[key1, value1], [key2, value2]]`

So in order to update it add `[action.item.id, action.item]`:

```
return {
  ...state,
  isFetching: false,
  didInvalidate: false

  items: [...state.items, [action.item.id, action.item]]
};
```